# How to execute java application (.exe / .jar / .bat) without displaying popup console at all?

Tags: java, batch-file, console, exe

I want to execute java application without displaying popup console. It because in 64bit applicaton, the GUI (console) will created in different session ID. I even use Java Service Wrapper, but the batch file still showing an popup console. So, how can I execute java application without displaying popup console? Or there any alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running following command in command prompt, or through a batch file should help you:

```batch
start javaw -jar -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m <Your Jar File>
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710839/start-a-java-program-without-the-console) thread for more.