# Python subprocess.run() call opens a console

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an application developed with python that makes a call to a subprocess.run(...) function when pushing a button in the interface:

```
subprocess.run(['java','-jar','myprogram.jar',testFile], capture_output=True)
```

This opens a temporary console that runs for a few seconds before closing itself.

Is there any way to avoid the console popping out?

Comment: Is this on windows or mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I hide the console when I use os.system() or subprocess.call()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006238/how-do-i-hide-the-console-when-i-use-os-system-or-subprocess-call)

Comment: If @msamsami 's link doesn't help, it could possibly be that the console is opened by the jar directly. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710839/start-a-java-program-without-the-console) could help you.

Comment: @whisplash The jar was opening the console, so your last comment helped! Thanks!